# Ping / SSH computer via SMB name

Tags: networking, ubuntu, samba, smb, netbios

At work, I can ping and SSH computers by either their IP or their SMB name.

If I try that at home (no, **I am not trying to access the office internal network from home**), then ping / SSH by IP address works fine, but SMB name fails.

(Just to clarify, **hosts do show up** in the smbtree and respond to pings by IP, just not by SMB name!).

At work there's a PFSense server managing the network. At home it's just a wireles router on a DSL line. All my devices on the home network are 192.168.1.x / 255.255.255.0 issued by DHCP.

The following is a sample from my home network.

```
user@computer:~$ smbtree -N
WORKGROUP
    \\UBUNTU-PC             computer server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        \\UBUNTU-PC\print$          Printer Drivers
        \\UBUNTU-PC\IPC$            IPC Service (computer server (Samba, Ubuntu))
    \\FILESERVER            fileserver server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        \\FILESERVER\Storage            
        \\FILESERVER\Videos     
        \\FILESERVER\Photos         
        \\FILESERVER\IPC$               IPC Service (fileserver server (Samba, Ubuntu))
user@computer:~$ nmblookup fileserver
querying fileserver on 192.168.1.255
192.168.1.9 fileserver<00>
user@computer:~$ ping fileserver
ping: unknown host fileserver
user@computer:~$ ssh fileserver
ssh: Could not resolve hostname fileserver: Name or service not known
```

`$ ifconfig` from my home PC

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Endereço de HW xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet end.: 192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Masc:255.255.255.0
          endereço inet6: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/64 Escopo:Global
          endereço inet6: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/64 Escopo:Global
          endereço inet6: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/64 Escopo:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Métrica:1
```

Comment: @FranciscoTapia of which hosts(s)? I have two laptops, a file server, a raspberry PI, two smartphones, and a tablet.

Comment: What os do you have at work? Windows ``ping`` (and other winsock tools) can resolve names using smb multicast, WSD multicast, lmhosts or wins (Depends on Node Type). But **nix ``ping``  uses ``resolve.conf``(for DNS) or ``yp.conf`` (for NIS) or ``hosts`` file. It can't use SMB name

Comment: @user996142 Ubuntu at both home and work. No config files modified.

Comment: Try to run ``nslookup <<COMPUTER_NAME>>`` at work. I am sure you will get anwer from DNS server. That means you can access this server from work, but not from home.

Comment: @user996142 I **do not** want to acess a remote machine from home!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrrect way to use SMB name resolution on a Linux machine is to edit (as *su*) the file */etc/nsswitch.conf* and to make sure that the line beginning with **hosts** contains *wins*, like this, for instance:

```
 hosts:          files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Of course you will be unable to contact any pc not running a SMB server, like for instance a Linux machine on which samba has not been downloaded, installed, and the NetBIOS name has not been provided in the */etc/samba/smb.conf* file as follows:

```
 workgroup = WORKGROUP
 NetBIOS name = MyPCName
```

You should also remember that firewall settings may block these requests.

Comment: Why is it that 10 pings to the IP address takes 9s but 10 pings to the NetBIOS name takes 50+ seconds?